# Citing a patent with biblatex ieee style

Tags: biblatex, citing, ieee-style

I want to cite a patent with

```
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ieee,
  sorting=nyt,
  bibencoding=utf8,
  defernumbers=true,
  maxnames=10,
  citestyle=numeric-comp
]{biblatex}
```

and this in my bib file:

```
@patent{s_1991,
  author      = {Claus-Peter Schnorr},
  title       = {Method for identifying subscribers and for generating and verifying electronic signatures in a data exchange system},
  nationality = {United States},
  number      = {4995082},
  day         = {19},
  month       = {2},
  year        = {1991},
  dayfiled    = {23},
  monthfiled  = {2},
  yearfiled   = {1990},
  url         = {https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?CC=US&NR=4995082},
}
```

The result I get in my bibliography though is:

[image: Result in bibliography]

I don't mind that the issue date is ignored, but why is the nationality ignored which is apparently very important (see e.g. [IEEEtran HowTo](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf#page=6)).

The work around I came up with is using

```
number    = {United States Patent 4995082},
```

but this should not be necessary, right?

Also: is the day of the patent not necessary as well?

Comment: Note that `day` is not a supported field in `biblatex`. If you want day-precision dates you need to use the `date` field. In your example you would replace `day = {19}, month = {2}, year = {1991},` with `date = {1991-02-19}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the `biblatex` [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), §2.1.1 *(Entry Types) Regular Types*, as it reads

> **Required fields**: `author`, `title`, `number`, `year`/`date`
>
> **Optional fields**:  `holder`, `subtitle`, `titleaddon`, `type`, `version`, `location`, `note`, `month`, `addendum`, `pubstate`, `doi`, `eprint`, `eprintclass`, `eprinttype`, `url`, `urldate`

It means that the supported fields for `@patent` do not include the `nationality` one; instead, you should use the field `type`, or `location` if the scope of the patent is different from the one indicated by `type`.

Moreover, as you can see from the above, many other fields that you are using in your `.bib` file are not supported as well.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much for the clarification! I guess my misconception has been to mix up IEEEtran with the biblatex ieee style.

Comment: @Linus, although see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/907 for possible future plans.